# How to split column text to another column

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a page where I display "posted" folders and documents by managers. When a text document gets posted it gets appended under a specific company folder based on the users choosing.  The issue I'm having is that the person that built this didn't display subfolders under the main folders but instead opted to display them the same way the main folders are displayed except if its a subfolder he'll name it "Mainfolder/Subfolder".

For instance, I created a main folder.
Posted a text file that was in that main folder, so now on the page it says.

> 1.MainFolder (once clicked on it expands)
>
> --MainDocument

If I place a subfolder in MainFolder and post its contents, it gets displayed like this:

> 2.MainFolder/SubFolder
>
> --SubFolderdocument

Refer to this fiddle to see how these get inserted into the table: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f24e/1

How can I fix this using php or mysql ?

I tried something like this but I'm not sure if theres a better way:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(folder,'/',-1),'/',1) AS Subfolder, folder as Mainfolder FROM `documents` WHERE active = 1 AND folder LIKE '%/%' GROUP BY folder
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Subfolder  |         Mainfolder         |
---------------------------------------------
| JoeSubFolder | JoeMainFolder/JoeSubFolder |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: well your procedure looks good. for main folder u can just do as `substring_index(folder,'/',1) as Mainfolder`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Ahh oops, don't know how I missed that, thanks. Now I just hope I can display the correct subfolders under their main folders using PHP.